# Cannot display Array

Tags: javascript

```
  var processResult = function(items)
{

    return  items;
};
    function queryDB(callback) {

            var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM DEMO";
            db.transaction(
                    function(tx) {
                        tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                                function(tx, results) {
                                    var item_Codes = [];
                                    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                                        item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode});
                                    }
                                    callback(item_Codes);
                                })
                                , errorCB;
                    });
            return false;
        }
```

**Main.js**

```
  queryDB(processResult, function(arr) {
            $.each(arr, function(i, elem) {

        });
    });
```

In above Code item_Codes is  array.Here i need to print the Array after  the data is loaded.But when i try to print the array it displays null. How Can i print the Array after the data is loaded to the Array.

Comment: Can you eloborate your answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the variable after the call, you use the parameter in the callback function that you send in the call:

```
queryDB(function(arr){
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: @user2889058: If you change your question to look like the answer, other people won't understand the answer.

Comment: Hwy sorry for the mistake.But  when i try i still gives me error.11-14 11:23:28.718: E/Web Console(8418): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function:67

Comment: @user2889058: Now you have two callback functions in the call, but the function only uses the first. It seems that the variable `processResult` doesn't exist where you use it, did you create it inside a function scope?

Answer (score 0):

why not you try :

```
function queryDB(callback) {



   var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM DEMO";
    db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                        function(tx, results) {
                            var item_Codes = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                                item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode});
                            }
                            callback(item_Codes);
                        })
                        , errorCB;
            });
    console.log(item_codes);
    return false;
}
```

That is, I am just trying to print out the value of your array after the code executes.

Comment: Actually i need to print the array from another file.